# Converting time input from 24hr clock , to seconds, and back to 24 hr format

Tags: c#, time, visual-studio-2015

What I need to do is take a time window on a 24hr clock ie: 1000-1100
convert it to seconds, which I can do.

(1000 / 100)*60 = 600

(1100 / 100)*60 = 660

Get 25% of the result(15), which I can also do. (660 / 4)

Add that 25% of additional seconds to the previous end time (1100)

The issue is that I am getting an output of 1100 instead of 1115
The Question is how do I make it output as 1115.

I do use constants to define hour and hundred so no magic numbers, these numbers are just illustrating the math.

```
    //define constants
    const int HUNDRED = 100;
    const int HOUR = 60;
    const int PERCENT = 4;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // recieve start time input
        string oldStart = oldStartTime.Text;
        int oldTimeIn = int.Parse(oldStart);

        // recieve end time input
        string oldEnd = oldEndTime.Text;
        int oldTimeEnd = int.Parse(oldEnd);

        // convert start time to minutes
        int hoursStart = (oldTimeIn / HUNDRED) * HOUR;
        int minutesStart = oldTimeIn % HUNDRED;
        int totalStart = hoursStart + minutesStart;

        // convert end time to minutes
        int hoursEnd = (oldTimeEnd / HUNDRED) * HOUR;
        int minutesEnd = oldTimeEnd % HUNDRED;
        int totalEnd = hoursEnd + minutesEnd;

        // calulate 25% of travel time ( end - start )
        int extraTime = totalEnd - totalStart;
        int totalMinutes = (extraTime / PERCENT);

        // convert back to hours            
        int newEndHours = (totalEnd + totalMinutes) / HOUR * HUNDRED;

        // out put new end time
        newEndTime.Text = $"{newEndHours:d4}";
```

Comment: Please show us your code, it will help us identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: Why dont you make use of the `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` classes? Dont reinvent the wheel :).

Comment: I have no idea what those are... I am really new and am just going off of what I've learned in my online class so far, and it hasn't said anything about DateTime and TimeSpan. Also this is a form if that helps

Comment: What is the requirement here? I'm not talking about the problem but the requirement itself.

Comment: the requirement is to add 25% of the original amount of time to the original (user input) end time

Comment: looks like by making all variables integers, your oldtimeend/100 is truncating the decimal you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int newEndHours = (totalEnd + totalMinutes) / HOUR * HUNDRED;
```

The operation is being done as integers, so the (660 + 15)/100 is coming out as 11. Remember that even if it was casted to doubles, it would result in 11.25, and not 11.15.

You will have to add in another part similar to when you deconstructed the time to handle the minutes part, so

```
int newEndHours = (totalEnd + totalMinutes) / HOUR * HUNDRED + (totalEnd + totalMinutes) % HOUR;
```